# how to set the value of an input field to the value of a session variable using jquery at the click of a button

Tags: jquery

I want to set the value of an input field to the value of session using jquery.

html code

```
<input type='text' id='examtitle' />

<input type='text' id='Qclass' />
<input type='text' id='examid' />

<input type='text' id='qclass' />

<input type='button' id='show' />
```

jquery

```
$("#show").on("click", function () {
// Set Session
var exam = document.getElementById('examtitle').value;
                                var quesclass = document.getElementById('Qclass').value;                              
 $(function () {
                                    $.session.set("examTitle", exam);
                                    $.session.set("questionClass", quesclass);
                                    // Set input value to session value
                                    $(function () {
                                        //alert($.session.get("examTitle"));
                                        $("#examid").val($.session.get("examTitle"));
                                        $("#qclass").val($.session.get("questionClass"));
                                    });
                            });
```

These codes worked partially as it flashes the session value in the input field. 
Please how do I make the session value stay on the input field instead of appearing and disappearing really very quickly?

Thank you

Comment: `'examid' != 'examtitle'` and `'qclass' != 'Qclass'`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited and Adjusted! 
This is what you are looking for.

HTML CODE

```
<input type='text' id='examtitle' />

<input type='text' id='class' />
<input type='text' id='examid' />

<input type='text' id='qclass' />

<input type='button' id='show' value="show" onclick="getSession()" />
```

I used pure JavaScript

JavaScript Code

```
function getSession() {
    var exam = document.getElementById('examtitle').value
    var quesClass = document.getElementById('class').value

    sessionStorage.setItem('examTitle', exam);
    sessionStorage.setItem('questionClass', quesClass);

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Samson Ugwu. I added the e.preventDefault(); but I still get the same result. tThe value won't stay on the input. Just shows and disappears quickly.

Comment: This works. Your previous post worked also with e.preventDefaulth() method. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

these inputs selectors does not seem to be found in the HTML markup you are using,

```
var exam = document.getElementById('examtitle').value;
var quesclass = document.getElementById('Qclass').value;
```

the examtitle ID and Qclass ID needs to be changed to the examid and qclass

Comment: Thanks for the observation @Moayad .AlMoghrabi. I included those in the edit i made.